# Injecting IServiceProvider into Factory Class with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a factory class in a Net Core 3 console app which needs to be able to resolve against a DI container at runtime:

```
public class OptionFactory : IOptionFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _svcProvider;

    public OptionFactory( IServiceProvider svcProvider )
    {
        _svcProvider = svcProvider;
    }

    public IOption<T>? CreateOption<T>( params string[] keys )
    {
        // code eliminated for brevity
        try
        {
            return retVal = _svcProvider.GetRequiredService<Option<T>>();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Autofac to define the DI container and then "assign" it to `IServiceProvider` via `new AutofacServiceProvider( builder.Build() )` in a provider class:

```
public class TestServiceProvider 
{
    public static IServiceProvider Instance { get; private set; }

    static TestServiceProvider()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<OptionFactory>()
            .As<IOptionFactory>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // code omitted for brevity
        Instance = new AutofacServiceProvider( builder.Build() );
    }
}
```

I'm unclear about how to register `IServiceProvider` itself with the DI container so that it can be injected into the constructor. Is that even possible? It seems a little self-referential, which could be problematic.

All the examples I've seen online call for referencing back to the Autofac `IContainer` itself, (or to `TestServiceProvider.Instance` in my example). I can do that, but it would end tie my library to a concrete service provider class. Which I think I'd like to avoid if I can.

I realize injecting `IServiceProvider` is considered an anti-pattern by some/many, although others deem it acceptable in a factory class because the factory is "simply" extending the DI container. I'm open to other approaches which don't rely on a factory class, provided they allow me to create concrete instances of open generic types at runtime.

Comment: An alternative idea could be to mark the IOption<T> (careful with name collisions with the Microsoft Configuration namespace) with a base IOption interface if you don't already do it, and in your factory have an IEnumerable<IOption> to be injected. You can gather the instances and return the one that matches in your method.

Comment: Good point about the collision, I'll fix that. The IEnumerable<> approach would work -- I use it fairly frequently -- but it requires (I think) knowing the possible derived generic types when IContainer is initialized. I'd prefer not to do have to specify those ahead of time (that's another aspect of the on-the-fly nature of what I'm trying to do). Thanx for the feedback!

Comment: That's why I threw in the idea of a base IOption interface, so you can resolve all these without specifying the actual derived type. It's a marker interface, just to help you gather them all

Comment: A great blog post with this idea is here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface (Steve Gordon has amazing content BTW )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of options (no pun intended ).

## Easiest: Call `builder.Populate()` with an empty collection

The `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package (which you're using, since you have `AutofacServiceProvider`) has an extension method `ContainerBuilder.Populate()` [which handles registering stuff from an `IServiceCollection` and auto-registering the `AutofacServiceProvider`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/ec38706c11d60e19d1d97ef12bc8f391b9f65ebf/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacRegistration.cs#L96). You could call that method with an empty service collection and it'll work.

```cs
builder.Populate(Enumerable.Empty<ServiceDescriptor>());
```

This will get you exactly the thing you're looking for. However, there's an alternative to consider...

## Alternative: Use `ILifetimeScope`

If it doesn't matter whether your `OptionFactory` is tied to Autofac, you can inject `ILifetimeScope`. Autofac has the current lifetime scope auto-registered, so this will work:

```cs
public OptionFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
{
  // scope is whatever lifetime scope the
  // factory itself came from - if that's the
  // root container, then the scope is the
  // container
}
```

The benefit here is you'll get the richer resolve options Autofac offers without any extra work. The drawback would be you're tied to Autofac at this level, which may or may not matter.

## Beware!

It may just be your example, but there's something important to know if you're resolving directly from the root container the way the example shows:

**You could easily end up with a big memory leak.**

Autofac holds on to all `IDisposable` instances it resolves so they can be safely disposed when the lifetime scope is disposed. If you are resolving from the container, that means any `IDisposable` will be held onto until the container itself is disposed, which, for most, is the lifetime of the application. That means - hypothetically - every resolution could be adding just a tiny little bit of memory that won't be disposed until the container is disposed. Memory leak.

For this reason we recommend [always resolving from a nested lifetime scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#always-resolve-dependencies-from-nested-lifetimes) rather than from the container. In a web app, that request-level lifetime scope is perfect because it disappears after a request. In an example like this, it's up to you and your app code to determine the best way to integrate lifetime scopes.

And, of course, if you're *definitely, 100% guaranteed* never resolving anything `IDisposable`, no worries.

Comment: Thanx, @Travis, for both the answer and for the detailed explanation. I've been using Autofac for a while (and love it) but the vast majority of my use cases haven't involved classes implementing IDisposable (at least not intentionally on my part :)) so I my understanding of life scopes has been hazy. But now it's improved!